# on change not fire on a list IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onchange

This is my html:

```
  <select name="City" id="lstCities" data-val-cityvalidator-toolongerror="Votre ville doit être composé d’un maximum de 35 caractères." data-val-cityvalidator-max="35" data-val-cityvalidator-mandatory="True" data-val-cityvalidator-emptyerror="Le champ « Ville » est obligatoire" data-val-cityvalidator-displaycities="True" data-val-cityvalidator-defaultvalue="Autre..." data-val-cityvalidator="The field City is invalid." data-val="true" class="valid"><option selected="selected" value="HERBLAY">HERBLAY</option><option value="PIERRELAYE">PIERRELAYE</option>
<option value="0">Autre...</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to fire on change event in IE9 like this:

```
    $("#lstCities").change(function () {
 alert('changed');
});
```

but the event don't fire, why?? this is my simple http://jsfiddle.net/mGAUn/     [lienjsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGAUn/)

Comment: You aren't including jQuery on that fiddle.

Comment: Works for me if you remember to include jQuery.

Comment: So your code works on other browser?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot you include jquery on that jsFiddle. If you include it, will work perfect on any browser.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mGAUn/4/) you have an updated jsFiddle that includes jQuery. Look at the left bar, the very top dropdown.

(I'm not allowed to post a jsFiddle link without code, so adding dummy code)

```
$("#lstCities").change(function () {
 alert('changed');
});
```